# "Potential of" or "potential for"?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

Which sentence should I use?

> 1. The potential for wind energy in Germany?
> 2. The potential of wind energy in Germany?

Comment: 1. sounds like how big wind energy could _be_ (itself; **in** Germany), whereas 2. sounds like how much wind energy could _mean_ (e.g., _be important_; **to** Germany).

Comment: Neither option is a sentence. (You'll need to include the entire sentence to get good answers.)

Comment: Even if either was a sentence, context would be everything.

In any case, what research did you do and where did that lead?

Answer (score 1):

As a native speaker I would say you could use either. To me "potential for" means the possibility of it working.Potentially it might work but it might not. Using "potential of" means to what extent it could be used. For example, how many people it might benefit, how it might reduce cost, how it might attract business, etc.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to ELU. Please take the [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and consider how you might [improve your answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). As it stands, this sounds like opinion. Can you cite references to show that this answer reflects general use?